# Multiple conditionals inside a trigger using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a trigger that will update a table called VIDEO after the table DETAILRENTAL is updated. I am trying to use  IF ELSE conditionals to satisfy multiple situations.

This is what I have coded:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_VIDEORENTAL_UP
AFTER UPDATE OF DETAIL_RETURNDATE ON DETAILRENTAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
 IF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL THEN
       UPDATE VIDEO
       SET VID_STATUS = 'OUT'
       WHERE :NEW.VID_NUM = VID_NUM;

ELSEIF
  :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE > SYSDATE
       UPDATE VIDEO
       SET VID_STATUS = 'OUT'
       WHERE:NEW.VID_NUM = VID_NUM;

ELSEIF
  :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE < SYSDATE OR :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE = SYSDATE 
       UPDATE VIDEO
       SET VID_STATUS = 'IN'
       WHERE :NEW.VID_NUM = VID_NUM;

ELSE 
   :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE = '01/01/01'
       UPDATE VIDEO
       SET VID_STATUS = 'LOST'
       WHERE :NEW.VID_NUM = VID_NUM ;

  END IF;
end;
```

This is the error message I get when I run this code:

> *Error at line 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:    := . ( @ % ;*

I already tested each conditional to ensure that each statement works individually but it does not seem to work together.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses `ELSIF`, not `ELSEIF` for multiple conditions.

That is probably the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `ELSEIF` [needing to be `ELSIF`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-B7DD4E62-3ED2-41E9-AAE5-90A78788BB31) as @Gordon pointed out, those `ELSIF` conditions still need a `THEN`:

```
ELSIF
  :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE > SYSDATE THEN
       UPDATE VIDEO
       ...
ELSIF
  :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE < SYSDATE OR :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE = SYSDATE THEN
       UPDATE VIDEO
       ...
```

and your final `ELSE` either needs to be an `ELSIF` plus `THEN`:

```
ELSIF 
   :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE = '01/01/01' THEN
       UPDATE VIDEO
       ...
```

or remove that condition:

```
ELSE
       UPDATE VIDEO
       ...
```

depending on the logic you actually need.

If you do need the condition, and thus the `ELSIF`, then the way you are comparing the date in that condition is wrong too; `'01/01/01'` is a string not a date, so you are relying on implicit conversion using the session's NLS settings, which you may not control. Use `to_date()` with a suitable format mask, or [an ANSI date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1):

```
ELSIF 
   :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE = DATE '2001-01-01' THEN
       UPDATE VIDEO
       ...
```